# Mixing PHP and html basic

Tags: php, html

In a var i want to mix php and html/ inline css, I think i'm almost there with the code below but it keeps failing.

```
$bgThumb = 'style="background-image:url(' . echo $url . ');"';
```

Comment: echo performs output immediately. it is NOT a function and has no return value, so you cannot assign `echo`ed data to a variable.

Comment: You can mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 2):

```
$bgThumb = 'style="background-image:url(' . $url . ');"';
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for echo to concatenate variables:

```
$bgThumb = 'style="background-image:url(' . $url . ');"';
```

`echo` just displays content in the webpage, it can't be used in the variable.

Comment: connect = 'concatenate'

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an echo in a variable!!!

```
$bgThumb = 'style="background-image:url(' . $url . ');"';
```

then

```
echo $bgThumb;
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to echo

```
$bgThumb = 'style="background-image:url(' . $url . ');"';
```